The King takes a stroll
I have got a fun chess puzzle here, have fun solving it!

In a game, the Black King is on a square that he likes. Unfortunately, he is under attack on that square. Your task is to find a sequence of (normal) moves (but without white moving) for the Black King that will return him to his desired square (a) without subjecting him to check at any time, (b) without taking him to any square (except his present one) more than once, and (c) doing all this in the minimum possible number of moves. On his tour, the Black King can capture some white pieces.


I suggest you write down your solution as follows:


Kd8 2. Ke8 3. ...


or if you are a minimalist and do not care about chess notation:


d8 2. e8 3. ...



This is a very fun puzzle! Thank you for making this

Interesting that the path turns out so long! That makes me wonder if it could be possible to force a full hamiltonian cycle for a puzzle like this (up to the placement of the wK of course)

The king can finish this job in

 32 moves at a minimum.

To get started,

 it is clear that he must capture all the white pieces except possibly the knights, the king and h2. Moreover, among the pieces in that list, he must capture in order Rg1, Bg7, Rb2 and Be2. Hence, the only way he can reach Rg1 is via f2 and e3. This square is protected by Nd5, so bK must capture there beforehand. These two must be the first captures (since a4 is needed later to reach b2).

As such, there are two shortest possible starting sequences, namely

 1. d7 2. (a) d6 (b) e6 3. d5 4. e4 5. e3 6. f2 7. g1

However, we will see that only the first one can lead to an overall minimal solution. Next,

 every way to get out without repeating a previous square must use g3, hence also h2. After that, Bg7 is the next capture in line, which cannot be reached from a square below due to the white king.

As a consequence, the shortest possible continuation is uniquely determined:

 8. h2 9. g3 10. f4 11. f5 12. e6 13. f7 14. g7

Crucially, as this sequence uses

 e6,

we see that the second variant of the first sequence cannot be used for a full solution! From there,

 the king must reach b2 via the path b6, a5, a4, a3.

At this point, there are three possible shortest paths to take while avoiding backtracking, here is just one:

 15. f6 16. e5 17. d4 18. c5 19. b6 20. a5 21. a4 22. a3 23. b2

At this point, the remaining shortest path is again unique and easily seen to be

 24. c2 25. d2 26. e2 27. d3 28. c4 29. b5 30. a6 31. b7 32. c8

In total, as each of these segments achieves its shortest possible length even without the constraint of no repeated squares, there are exactly three shortest possible paths the king can take. In total, one of them is

 1. d7 2. d6 3. d5 4. e4 5. e3 6. f2 7. g1 8. h2 9. g3 10. f4 11. f5 12. e6 13. f7 14. g7 15. f6 16. e5 17. d4 18. c5 19. b6 20. a5 21. a4 22. a3 23. b2 24. c2 25. d2 26. e2 27. d3 28. c4 29. b5 30. a6 31. b7 32. c8

Or, if you prefer it drawn on the board:

 

This was a cute puzzle and I enjoyed solving it a lot!

Could you draw the path in an image? That would look nice I think.

@Lezzup I have included a picture of the solution now

Ignoring the fact that you can't repeat squares, the captures of the white pieces are (in order, except possibly those in brackets)

 d5, g1, g7, b2, e2, (a4), b5, b6, b7, b8

You can do this by

  1. d7 2. d6 3. d5
 4. e4 5. e3 6. f2 7. g1
 (Now need to capture h2 to give space to exit)
 8. h2 9. g3 10. f4 11. f5 12. e6 13. f7 14. g7
 Need to capture a2 (and thus a4) to get to b2. Note: I used two more move than is necessary here
 15. g8 16. f8 17. e8 18. d8 19. c7 20. b6 21. a5 22. a4
 23. a3 24. a2
 25. b2
 Now finish the job straightforwardly
 26. c2 27. d2 28. e2
 29. d3 30. c4 31. b5
 32. a6
 33. b7
 34. c8

The whole sequence

 is 34 moves.

